# Java NumberFormat adds extra digit to output for particular number input

Tags: java, android, number-formatting

I have a method using Java NumberFormat to format and return a string with commas for float inputs.

```
public static String takeFloatAddCommasPlain(float fNumber){
    NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
    return numberFormat.format(fNumber);
}
```

It works fine except when the input is 40000.08. I have gone through the input and output at the points where I call this method in my debugger and my findings are as below;

> When the input is 30000.256
> [image: When the input is 30000.256]

[image: When the input is 30000.256]

> When the input is 40000.08
> [image: When the input is 40000.08]

[image: When the input is 40000.08]

One interesting bit was when I input the number directly in the Expression Evaluator, it returned it fine;
[image]

Comment: It must be that the value passed in the second case is not the one you think it is (i.e: 40000.08).

Comment: I've checked and followed it along with the debugger